# How to build a maven scaffold like spring initializr

Tags: spring, maven, maven-plugin, quarkus

As the title, is there such a maven plugin that can achieve such a function, I can manually select the required dependencies, or even generate the code automatically?

Comment: Please add more details and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You can create Maven project with `mvn archetype:generate` command. For example:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.roamch007 -DartifactId=my-app -DinteractiveMode=false
```

This command will create project in `may-app` directory.

If you need specific dependencies you can create Maven Archetype, and re-use this archetype while generating new projects.

Read more: [Guide to Maven Archetype](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-archetype)

Answer (score 1):

There is https://code.quarkus.io/ for generating projects from the browser and also the `quarkus` https://quarkus.io/guides/cli-tooling if you want to use a command line application